# .Net Core 3.1 react application with identity authentication - 403 Error Access is denied using provided credentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

When i attempt to access a .NET core 3.1 web application deployed in IIS i'm receiving the following error:

[image]

This error is misleading.  I never had the opportunity to enter my login credentials because the login page didn't render. 
I created this project in Visual Studio 2019 with react and individual user account authentication.  How can i make the login page the first to render?

Details about publishing to IIS:
-From Visual Studio 2019 i published this project using the self-containted deployment type.  Target framework = netcoreapp3.1, Target runtime win-x64
   -I have also tried the Framework-Dependent deployment Type since the target server does have the .net core 3.1 hosting bundle installed.

Here's the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\site_2020.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Http To Https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here's appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\EXAMPLE_TEST;Database=SITE_TEST;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "site_2020": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "Personal",
      "StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
      "Name": "*.example.com"
    }
  },
  "JWT": {
    "Site": "https://secure.api.example.com",
    "SigninKey": "A Random Sting. wrkafjsdlkajreoiajfkljoiajweoir",
    "ExpiryInMinutes": "60"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here's startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
readonly string AllowSpecificOrigins = "_allowSpecificOrigins";

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o =>
            {               
                o.AddPolicy(AllowSpecificOrigins, b => b.WithOrigins("http://example.com", "https://example.com", 
                    "https://localhost:44378", "http://localhost:50296")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
                IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    var onTokenValidated = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        await onTokenValidated(context);
                    };
                });

            services.AddDbContext<HcrDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddMvc();
            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            services.AddScoped<SiteInterface, SiteRepository>();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors(AllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  The target server is Windows Server 2019 VM on Azure.  The Azure security group does allow HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: According to the error message it seems that you don't have the permission to access the web site roo directory. This is not identity throw error. Could you please post how you publish the web application to the IIS and the IIS site folder make up.

Comment: added additional deployment details above

Comment: After following devpro's post below i am now receiving this error:   Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject '*.example.com, rest of cert subject.' on the 'LocalMachine\Personal'.  when i run certmgr.msc i do see the cert there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any use of .UseCore() in Startup Configure() method.

Can you try with it between UseAuthorization and UseEndpoints?

```
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => ...);
```

You could also add AllowAnyHeader and AllowAnyMethod in ConfigureServices method.

```cs
services.AddCors(o =>
{               
    o.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder => { 
        builder
            .WithOrigins("http://example.com", "https://example.com", "https://localhost:44378", "http://localhost:50296")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
   });
});
```

Comment: I made these changes now i'm receiving a 500 error There is a problem with the resource you are looking for and cannot be displayed

Comment: It's a good thing, 500 errors are easier to investigate!

Do you see the details of the HTTP response? (like in the Network pane of the Console window of your browser)

Make sure that the website runs with environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development to get the exception detail page.

Your logging configuration seems right.

Is there something in ".\logs\stdout"? (like a trace message)

(I don't know if it's a possibility but it's much easier and performant to host an ASP.Core in Azure as an Azure Web App.)

Comment: I am seeing this error in Event Viewer:  Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site-test\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\site_2020.dll' with multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '26080'

Comment: I didn't realize i could do this as an Azure Web App.  I don't have any experience with that.